# Is there a way to get the variables from the mutation update function?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

When using Apollo's Mutation component, is there any way of getting the mutation's variables from inside the update callback function?

```
<Mutation
  mutation={mutation}
  update={(cache, result) => {
    // is there any way to get the mutation variables here?
  }}
>
  {mutate => <MyComponent onSubmit={mutate} />}
</Mutation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that information is not passed to the update function. You'll need to move the `Mutation` component inside `MyComponent` (or lift your state *up* and out of `MyComponent`) so that you can pass the variables directly to the `Mutation` component, instead of the `mutate` function:

```
<Mutation
  mutation={mutation}
  variables={{ ... }}
  update={()=> {
    // Now whatever values you used for the mutation will also be available here
  }}
>
{mutate => {
  // mutate can be used without passing any variables to it
}}
</Mutation>
```

You may have a unique use case, but normally we wouldn't need to worry about the variables in the first place. Typically, insert, delete and update mutations return the inserted/deleted/updated object and that payload would be sufficient to update the cache. If your mutation is *not* returning the mutated data, and you have the ability to change the API, you may consider doing so since that will help as well.

Comment: Thank, I was afraid that was the case. Anyway, I can get the data from the mutation result, but it would mean traveling an extra node in the graph. I'll think about it